# Previous group match in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I try to capture fragments of string that looks like `%a`, `%b`, etc. and replace them with some values. Additionally, I want to be able to escape `%` character by typing `%%`.

In an example string `%d%%f%x%%%g` I want to match `%d%%f%x%%%g` (`%d`, `%x`, `%g`).

My regular expression looks like this:

```
(?:[^%]|^)(?:%%)*(%[a-z])
```

- `(?:[^%]|^)` - match to the beginning of the line or the character different from `%`
- `(?:%%)*` - match to 0 or more occurrences of `%%` (escaped `%`)
- `(%[a-z])` - proper match to `%a`, `%b`, etc. patterns

First two elements are added to support escaping of `%` character.

However, when running the regexp on example string the last fragment (`%g`) is not found:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile("(?:[^%]|^)(?:%%)*(%[a-z])")
>>> pat.findall("%d%%f%x%%%g")
['%d', '%x']
```

but after adding a character before `%%%g`, it starts to work fine:

```
>>> pat.findall("%d%%f%x %%%g")
['%d', '%x', '%g']
```

It looks like `x` is not matched again to `[^%]` after matching to the group `(%[a-z])`. How can I change the regexp to force it to check the last character of previous match again? I read about `\G`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why it didn't pick the `%g`?

To pick the `%g`, it must have to have `%%` before it. And even before that it must have to have a  `non-%` character, or at the beginning of the string. So, `x%%%g` could have a match for you. But this `x` was picked during previous matching(i.e. when printing `%x`).

In simple, you have overlapping on your regex matching. So you can overcome this using following one. I am placing your regex inside the `(?= ... )`

```
pat = re.compile("(?=(?:[^%]|^)(?:%%)*(%[a-z]))")
```

Comment: Good explanation, although the regex doesn't need to be that complicated.

Comment: Good explanation, although the regex doesn't need to be that complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct your regex a little differently:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?:[^%]|%%)*(%[a-z])")
>>> regex.findall("%d%%f%x%%%g")
['%d', '%x', '%g']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:      # Start of a non-capturing group:
 [^%]    # Either match any character except %
|        # or
 %%      # match an "escaped" %.
)*       # Do this any number of times.
(        # Match and capture in group 1:
 %[a-z]  # % followed by a lowercase ASCII alphanumeric
)        # End of capturing group
```

Comment: Good explanation, although the regex doesn't need to be that complicated.

Comment: Your solution will match `%%f` which is not correct as `%%` should be interpreted as escaped `%`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want to catch only every portion `%x` that is preceded by an even number of `%`.

If so, the pattern is  `"(?<!%)(?:%%)*(%[a-z])"`

Comment: Simple pattern, although there is no explanation. :)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve!